# How can I snap a mesh to the grid, on dragging it into the scene, in Unity?

Tags: unity, editors, instancing, position

I've got a game that involves voxel-like game object management. Each voxel object snaps to the integer coordinates in Unity's scene, at play time—easy enough to do in the `Start` function. Just floor every coordinate, and your origin is where you need it to be.

However, I may be placing some of these voxels before runtime, and would very much like them to snap to the grid while I'm dragging them into the scene. (I don't have any specific advantage in placing such a mesh halfway between valid locations.) If there's a way to ensure this in the editor, great; if there's a way for me to enforce it in code, that's even better.

Does such a facility exist in Unity?

Comment: Have you tried using OnValidate?

Comment: I have not. Does that get called when the object is dropped in the scene?

Comment: That seems like something you could test in about as much time as it takes to type that comment. I would, but I'm on a bus right now.

Comment: I appreciate the consideration... the project was loading until a moment ago, it's at a half gig in size! Anyway, this seems to do the job on compilation--everything snaps into place, but not on a change of the position value. I think it might be the right track though.

Comment: What's also interesting is that it's called after Control+Z.

Comment: It's starting to look like there may not be an easy (and also efficient) solution... I may just have to tolerate this.

Comment: You asked for a solution that runs when you drop the object into the scene, not for when moving it within a scene. When moving within a scene, you can get snapping automatically just by holding CTRL.

Comment: Yeah, I did, and as I said, it isn't even called on a scene drop, so it isn't a solution at all. Additionally, control locks to quarter units, not singles, so it isn't a real solution either, though if it's possible to set it to a different snapping value it would be useful information.

Comment: Are you looking for Edit > Grid and Snap Settings?

Comment: I had no idea that was there, thanks. This will definitely make life easier.